# SQL Server Management Studio dialogue cut off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

When trying create an Extended Events Session on a SSAS instance using the SSMS GUI, the Advanced tab (and only that) is visually cut off, only displaying part of the dialogue.

So far I have tried restarting both SSMS as well as the whole machine, but the problem persists. Coworkers I asked did not encounter this problem.

My next steps would be to re-install the latest SSMS version, but I thought I would ask the community first if anyone ever encountered such a problem and knows a fix.

[image]

Comment: I also tried the fix described in a similar issue, but this did yield any results either. https://superuser.com/questions/1319376/sql-server-management-studio-graphical-glitches?rq=1

Comment: What is your display resolution and display scaling set to? Have you checked compatibility settings of the application to make sure nothing was changed there?

Comment: I am using two displays, one 1920*1080 and one 3440*1440. The smaller display has scaling set to 125%, the bigger one 100%. The problem persists on both displays. The application runs under default settings and no changes have been made there.

Comment: This is a pretty typical issue with display scaling. Change both to 100% then log off and log back on and see if the problem is resolved. Alternatively, you can try to change the application’s compatibility mode settings. Right-click the application icon and click properties then compatibility. Use the “override display scaling” setting and change it to “system”. Additionally, I think there is a button or something to check to make sure the settings are for all users and not just the current user, but I’m not able to check right now.

Comment: There is a selection "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:" in which I set "System" and started the program again, but this did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, but first confirm is it is a scaling issue by setting scaling to 100% on both monitors and log off and log back on. Do that first, then solve the scaling issue if it is a scaling issue. It is just a guess at this point.

Comment: I changed scaling to 100% on both monitors, rebooted, nothing changed.
Then I shut down the machine, unplugged the second monitor (it's one of those huge 34 inch beasts btw) and started the PC again, but this also didn't change a thing.

Funny enough, two other colleagues have the same issue, while it works for a third coworker.